# Crash using character pointer; no crash using plain character — but why?

Tags: c, pointers

I just wrote a very simple string reversing function and faced a problem that I am not able to understand:

```
void reverse(char *data) {
    int length = 0,i;   
    char *temp,*start,*end;
    start = data;
    end = data;
    length = strlen(data);
    end = end + (length -1);
    for(i=0; i< length/2; i++) {
        *temp = *end;
        *end = *start;
        *start = *temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    int length1 = 0;
    char data1[100] = "I am megharaj from india";
    printf("data1 %s\n", data1);
    reverse(data1);
    printf("reversed\n");
    printf("data1 %s\n", data1);    
    return 0;
}
```

This gives segmentation fault, but if I change the `char *temp` to `char temp` then everything works fine, as shown below:

```
void reverse(char *data) {
    int length = 0,i;   
    char temp,*start,*end;
    start = data;
    end = data;
    length = strlen(data);
    end = end + (length -1);
    printf("length %d\n", length);
    for(i=0; i< length/2; i++) {
        temp = *end;
        *end = *start;
        *start = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Unable to understand the reason; can you explain, please?

Comment: Your first code is working fine for me : http://ideone.com/T1xicY

Comment: Because temp is your temporary *value*. It should be the same data type as your pointers, without the pointer.

Comment: @jester if it is, its by sheer luck. Its undefined behavior through and through. Look at the usage of `temp` in the first sample.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep, noticed it just now.. uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @jester leave that comment up, its a testimony to U in UB. Maybe it "worked", maybe it didn't, but since its not defined to, it doesn't really matter =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep i`m leaving it there.. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `char *temp;` and:

```
*temp = *end;
```

you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer and writing to an undefined location, invoking undefined behaviour and (fortunately for you) crashing.  The crash is not guaranteed.  When you use `char temp;`, you have made the compiler allocate the space for the `char` value. With the pointer, you've got 4 or 8 bytes of storage for the pointer itself, but it needs to point at a character location — and you've not set it to do so.  (Nor should you; the `char *temp` version is basically a mistake.)

- Use the version that doesn't crash.
- When you use a pointer, always ensure you know what it is pointing at.

Comment: +1 look no further than jester's general-comment about how "first code is working fine" as evidence you simply cannot rely on UB-presence.

Comment: Purely semantics, but I think it is incorrect to say that space is "allocated" for automatic variables (eg, on the stack).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: hmmm...what word would you use in place of 'allocated'?  The storage is allocated on the stack (on normal machines that have stacks).  It is not dynamically allocated in the sense of `malloc()`, though clearly it is allocated by the runtime system on demand (when the function is called) and freed by the runtime system.  The space for the character is 'there'; the space for the character is not 'there' for the pointer version — though the pointer is overkill anyway (8 bytes to point at a 1 byte space, instead of just using a 1 byte space).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I'm not sure.  I suppose "allocated on the stack" is a common enough phrase, and at the moment it sounds okay to me.  But 23 minutes ago it just sounded weird!  Not enough sleep, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

`char *temp` is not initialized anywhere - you are dereferencing garbage value here:

```
*temp = *end;
```

`temp` has storage class `auto` and is not initialized to anything by default.

Use a `char` instead. Like:

```
char temp;
```

Also you need 1 `char` less than length of string so that you ignore the `NUL` character:

```
end = end + (length-1 ); // I added this part because in your intial code 
//(on posting question) this line was end = end + (length);
```

Corrected code:

```
void reverse(char *data) {
    int length = 0,i;   
    char temp,*start,*end;
    start = data;
    end = data;
    length = strlen(data);
    end = end + (length-1 );
    for(i=0; i< length/2; i++) {
        temp = *end;
        *end = *start;
        *start = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Here is the [full program](http://ideone.com/MJiiiA)

Comment: Yes, I am doing it by length-1

Answer (score 1):

*start is pointing to data1 array i'e here `start = data;`

*end is pointing to data1 array i'e here `end= data;`

but `*temp` is not pointing anywhere.

The memory is not allocated for `char *temp` and you are trying to store value of `*end` in `*temp`,so it will give segmentation fault.

instead try using

```
char temp;
```